# Formatting data retrieved by curl GET

Tags: json, curl

Using curl, I have a GET function that is working great to retrieve the data (from Trello's API), but it comes out as a JSON that is all on one line. The software I'm using to read and interpret the retrieved data can only read lines of 32,000 characters.

Does anyone know a way to get it to include carriage returns in the way it does when you open it in Notepad++ and choose JSON Viewer (or any other manner).

The curl code is:

```
{LocationOfCurlOnMyServer} -H "Content-Type: text; charset=utf-8" 

-o "{OutputFileName}" 

--request GET --url "{TrelloURL}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jq JSON parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) along with curl :

```
curl -L "http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json" | jq '.' > output.json
```

Comment: You, my friend, are an International Super Hero!!! That worked PERFECTLY!!

Thank you SO much!